# No applicable method for 'count' applied to object of class "NULL", inside a function

Tags: r

I have tried to make a function that calculates percentage of observations that are below a certain amount of days. When i try to run the function with a supplied dataset no errors occur, but no variable is added to Tabel

Dput(dif$timedif) data is this:

```
c(-5, 34, -3, -8, 26, -3, -18, -4, 0, 21, 1229, 63, -3, -7, -2, 
0, -31, -15, -26, 0, 1691, 5, -3, 7, -186, -7, -3, -52, 0, -1, 
-1, -29)
```

I create a filtered dataset that i would like to use the function on. This has a column named "timedif"

```
library(dplyr)
dif<-dataset %>% filter(age_group=="60-80")
procentfunc<-function(x){
  absdi<-abs(x$timedif)
  pro0<-(sum(x$timedif==0))/count(x)*100
  pro1<-sum(absdi<7)/count(x)*100
  pro30<-sum(absdi<30)/count(x)*100
  pro90<-sum(absdi<90)/count(x)*100
  pro1y<-sum(absdi<365.25)/count(x)*100
  pro2y<-sum(absdi<(365.25*2))/count(x)*100
  pro3y<-sum(absdi<(365.25*3))/count(x)*100
  Tabel$x <-as.numeric(c(pro0,pro1,pro30,pro90,pro1y,pro2y,pro3y))
  }
procentfunc(x=dif)
```

When i try to apply my function to the dif dataset (the last line) it does not add anything to Tabel, which is what i was hoping for

Any idea how to move on from here so that when i run the function with a certain data set as x, it returns the output of the function into a variable in Tabel?
I am new at R so the function itself is most likely an abomination, but i hope it can serve my purpose.

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide the value of `dif` using `dput(dif)` or `dput(head(dif))`. What do you mean when you write “ When i try to run the last line …”? If you’re doing this *outside* your function, the error is not too surprising.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. The dput data in the question is from dput(dif$timedif). The other variables in the set are gender, age etc. I have saved my function as above, then i try to run procentfunc(x=dif) to apply dif to my functions, and my hope is that this will add the different percentages to Tabel as a new colum. However nothing happens apart from the error.

Comment: We need to *see* your data, not read your description of it.  Though, as someone else has suggested, your problem is most likely caused by a typo.  Also, are you aware that your function will return `NULL`?

Comment: `pro3y<-sum(absdi<(365.25*3))/count()*100` you are missing the `x` in `count(x)` in this line.

Comment: @Limey, why do you say this function returns `NULL`? AFAICT, it will return the invisible "value" of the `<-` assignment, which should be the value of the `as.numeric(..)` vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several issues to resolve here.

1. R usually prefers functions to *not* work in [side effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science)), though you are trying to do that with your `Tabel$x <- ...` expression. Even if `Tabel` is found in R's search (likely in the `.GlobalEnv`), because of R's copy-on-write semantics, this does nothing to the "real" `Tabel`. (If you want to go further down the path of "bad practice", look at `<<-` or `assign`. I strongly discourage this way.)
2. Even if we do go down the road if side-effect, the fact that this function is not passed `Tabel` in some way means this function breaches scope. While this can be made to work, it is fragile, can produce errors in odd ways, is not reproducible, is not idempotent, and can make troubleshooting problems around it much harder. In general, a function should only work with data it is passed or that it explicitly creates/calculates.
3. Your function is not explicitly returning anything, so it will implicitly return the last expression. In this case, this is the value of `as.numeric(...)`, whether or not `Tabel` is updated in-place (it is not, here). I suggest you should be updating `Tabel` *outside* of this function, perhaps with `Tabel$x <- procentfunc(x=dif)`.
4. `count` expects and returns a `data.frame`. While `count(x)*100` works, it also returns a `data.frame`, and since you're vectorizing things later in the function, it seems more appropriate to convert this into a number, as in `count(x)$n` ... or perhaps more simply, `nrow(x)`, the same value afaict.

I'll fabricate what might be representative of your real environment. I'll tweak the function based on the comments above (and simplify the expressions a little) and update a `Tabel` object safely.

```r
dif <- data.frame(timedif=c(-5, 34, -3, -8, 26, -3, -18, -4, 0, 21, 1229, 63, -3, -7, -2, 0, -31, -15, -26, 0, 1691, 5, -3, 7, -186, -7, -3, -52, 0, -1, -1, -29))
Tabel <- data.frame(id=1:7)
procentfunc <- function(x) {
  absdi <- abs(x$timedif)
  pro0 <- (sum(x$timedif == 0))
  pro1 <- sum(absdi < 7)
  pro30 <- sum(absdi < 30)
  pro90 <- sum(absdi < 90)
  pro1y <- sum(absdi < 365.25)
  pro2y <- sum(absdi < (365.25*2))
  pro3y <- sum(absdi < (365.25*3))
  as.numeric(c(pro0, pro1, pro30, pro90, pro1y, pro2y, pro3y)) / (nrow(x) * 100)
}
Tabel
#   id
# 1  1
# 2  2
# 3  3
# 4  4
# 5  5
# 6  6
# 7  7
Tabel$x <- procentfunc(x = dif)
Tabel
#   id         x
# 1  1 0.0012500
# 2  2 0.0046875
# 3  3 0.0078125
# 4  4 0.0090625
# 5  5 0.0093750
# 6  6 0.0093750
# 7  7 0.0093750
```

I'm assuming that your `Tabel` frame has 7 rows (that is the length of the `as.numeric(..)` vector), and that either it does not have a pre-existing column `"x"` or you are intending to overwrite it.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for the elaborate answer. I've tried to alter the code  according to your alterations and it seems way more reliable now. I am trying to avoid bad-practices, but as completely new in any sort of programming im doing this as much as possible when i encounter them, so i will look up your suggestion. Thanks for the help!